# Upload image or file via google hangout webhook

Tags: webhooks, google-hangouts

I needed to upload images via hangout webhook. Is there anyway to don that ?
Please provide api end point through which i can upload images through webhook

Answer (score -1):

I am looking for a solution to this as well. Haven't found it yet, but the workaround I am going with till then is to upload the file on drive/GitHub and sending the link as a text message.